# Wrapping a JavaScript callback redefining "this"

Tags: javascript

I know about `call` and `apply` in JavaScript, but I'm currently stuck with the following scenario.

I'm using **Benchmarkjs**, and it has an API defined like this:

```
.on(eventType, listener)
```

So I'd do, for instance:

```
/* Register the onStart callback */
suite.on('start', onStart);
```

My `onStart` function will be called so that `this === suite`.

How can I do so that I can define one of the `arguments` of `onStart`?

My code is something like this:

```
foo = function() {
   this.suite.on('start', this.onStart);
}
```

I'd like my `onStart` function to have a reference to `foo`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `bind` to override `this` and insert parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `Function.prototype.bind` for creating partial applications / curried functions.

`.bind()` takes the *context* as first parameter and all following passed in parameters will be used as *formal parameters* for the bound function invocation.

```
suite.on( 'start', this.onStart.bind( this, foo ) );
```

The reference to `foo` will now be available to `onStart()` as very first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` to `onStart` by wrapping it in a function.

```
foo = function() {
    this.suite.on('start', function(arguments){onStart(arguments, this)});
}
```

I prefer passing it instead of using `bind`, since `bind` isn't supported by IE 8 and lower.

Comment: This will lose the arguments to `onStart` that are passed to it by Benchmarkjs.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene: whoops, forgot about that.
Kindof ugly, but this works.